# Google play store release check

Tags: android, google-play

google play store does automated checking before the app is released to verify the application does not violate any of it's policies. My app is not yet ready for public release, but I would like to verify it would go through the check so far (I do not believe there is any violation, but I would like to be sure). Therefore it would be likely it would be accepted after I have finished the final touches.

Is there a way to run your application through the checking process without doing a public release? Does alpha/beta version run through the same checks?

Comment: You can refer this link https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/ . As far as I am aware, Yes even the Alpha and Beta apps go through the checking policy. But it is always better to be sure, as any suspended app will decrease the reputation of you Develope account.

Comment: Hi @Rahulrr2602, I have looked through the content policy and did the launch check https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/launch-checklist.html and I do believe I am clean there, but I would still like to recheck. 
I have read somewhere for example that some developers had problem since ios app used the same icons or logos and had to contact support and provide documents that they have the right to use those...

Comment: I know there are many issues like these. But a better approach to this issue would be creating a new Icon(Without taking the base of the icon from anywhere) for the app. Also, you can use Image Searches available to check if there is any other icon same as yours which exists. But I am pretty much not sure whether Google suspends app due to using the same Icon as other apps in IOS. I think all the reason for which an app will be suspended are mention in that link, even though I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted google play developer support and verified rahulrr2602 answer. Thanks!

If you would like to have your app complete the review process in advance, you have a few options:

If  you are submitting a APK update, you can turn on timed publishing. This will allow your update to complete the review process, however it will not be pushed to users until you have selected the "Go live" option. You can find more information about this in our help center here:  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282?hl=en

Or if you are trying to publish your app for the first time, you can submit your APK as a Closed Alpha or Beta test. This will allow your app to go through the review process, however it will not be served to users until your promote it to production or add testers to your testing list. You can find more information about how to set up a Alpha or Beta test here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en